# Rust persistent TcpStream

Tags: sockets, tcp, rust

I seem to be struggling with the std::io::TcpStream. I'm actually trying to open a TCP connection with another system but the below code emulates the problem exactly.

I have a Tcp server that simply writes "Hello World" to the TcpStream upon opening and then loops to keep the connection open.

```
fn main() {
  let listener = io::TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1", 8080);
  let mut acceptor = listener.listen();
  for stream in acceptor.incoming() {

    match stream {
      Err(_) => { /* connection failed */ }
      Ok(stream) => spawn(proc() {
        handle(stream);
      })
    }
  }
  drop(acceptor);
}

fn handle(mut stream: io::TcpStream) {
  stream.write(b"Hello Connection");
  loop {}
}
```

All the client does is attempt to read a single byte from the connection and print it.

```
fn main() {
    let mut socket = io::TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1", 8080).unwrap();
    loop {
      match socket.read_byte() {
        Ok(i) => print!("{}", i),
        Err(e) => {
          println!("Error: {}", e);
          break
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is my client remains blocked on the read until I kill the server or close the TCP connection. This is not what I want, I need to open a TCP connection for a very long time and send messages back and forth between client and server. What am I misunderstanding here? I have the exact same problem with the real system i'm communicating with - I only become unblocked once I kill the connection.

Comment: I think this needs an updated answer, as [rust has async I/O now](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/09_example/03_tests.html).

Comment: There is also [`socket2`](https://docs.rs/socket2/latest/socket2/index.html), with `TcpKeepAlive` parameters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, Rust does not have any facility for asynchronous I/O now. There [are](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/219) some attempts to rectify the situation, but they are far from complete yet. That is, there is a desire to make truly asynchronous I/O possible (proposals include selecting over I/O sources and channels at the same time, which would allow waking tasks which are blocked inside an I/O operation via an event over a channel, though it is not clear how this should be implemented on all supported platforms), but there's still a lot to do and there's nothing really usable now, as far as I'm aware.

You can emulate this to some extent with timeouts, however. This is far from the best solution, but it works. It could look like this (simplified example from my code base):

```
let mut socket = UdpSocket::bind(address).unwrap();

let mut buf = [0u8, ..MAX_BUF_LEN];
loop {
    socket.set_read_timeout(Some(5000));
    match socket.recv_from(buf) {
        Ok((amt, src)) => { /* handle successful read */ }
        Err(ref e) if e.kind == TimedOut => {}  // continue
        Err(e) => fail!("error receiving data: {}", e)  // bail out
    }

    // do other work, check exit flags, for example
}
```

Here `recv_from` will return `IoError` with `kind` set to `TimedOut` if there is no data available on the socket during 5 seconds inside `recv_from` call. You need to reset the timeout before inside each loop iteration since it is more like a "deadline" than a timeout - when it expires, all calls will start to fail with timeout error.

This is definitely not the way it should be done, but Rust currently does not provide anything better. At least it does its work.

**Update**

There is now an attempt to create an asynchronous event loop and network I/O based on it. It is called [`mio`](https://github.com/carllerche/mio). It probably can be a good temporary (or even permanent, who knows) solution for asynchronous I/O.

Comment: OK so I won't be able to do proper asynchronous I/O ... bummer. But why can I not read data from the TcpStream until the connection has closed? Is it implemented to buffer all data until EOF?

Comment: @Upio, didn't you say this: "Now the problem is my client remains blocked on the read until I kill the server or close the TCP connection"? This is "reading data from the TcpStream until the connection has closed", isn't it? Anyway, `TcpStream` is a [`Reader`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Reader.html), so it has [`read_to_end()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Reader.html#method.read_to_end) method which consumes all of the stream until it is closed. Is that what you need?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I already know how to interact with the reader. I would just like to understand why no data is read at the client side until the connection closes. Even i use read_byte(), it blocks until the connection terminates. How is this working internally?

Comment: @Upio, but how do you expect it to work? `read_byte()` attempts to read the next byte from the connection; this boils down to the lowest-level `read()` system call which will block the current thread until that byte is read or some error occurs. The only way (without async I/O) to signal that there is nothing more to read is to close the connection from the writing side, which will trigger EOF "error" on the reading side. That's how sockets work.

Comment: I expect the bytes sent from the server to be available after they are sent, not after the connection is closed. Which is the behaviour i'm seeing. I block and read no data at all until i close the connection. I thought it would read each byte sent, print it to the terminal and then block until the connection closes.

Comment: @Upio, ah, that's what you mean. Yes, the bytes are not printed, but this is not sockets fault, in fact. Standard output in Rust is line-buffered, so your `print!()` calls are executed, but their output is not flushed to the terminal. Change `print!()` to `println!()` in the client and you'll see it.